# И еще знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

И еще оттуда же: "По-над берегом все, как бурлаки — и люди и кони, все тянут на канатах струги, не жалея себя".
Особенно интересует: нужна ли запятая после слова "бурлаки"?

Answer (score 1):

Приятно подумать о пунктуации красивого предложения...
Думаю, что в этом случае запятая, завершающая сравнение,  заменена на тире **во избежание двусмыленности**. Автор хочет сказать, что "как бурлаки" были "и люди и кони". Если бы вместо тире стояла запятая, ..,КАК БУРЛАКИ,И ЛЮДИ И КОНИ, получился бы ряд однородных членов БУРЛАКИ,ЛЮДИ,КОНИ. Замена традиционной запятой на тире производится именно с целью избежать двусмысленности и искажения речевого замысла.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы знаки расставила так:
"По-над берегом все, как бурлаки: и люди, и кони -  все тянут на канатах струги, не жалея себя".

Comment: Можно и так. Но у Вас получилось БСП. Смысл поменялся. Запятую тогда надо убирать перед "как", ибо "как бурлаки" стало сказуемым при подлежащем "все". А во второй части "все" стало обобщающим словом для "люди", "кони". Это подлежащие при сказуемом "тянут". В исходном же предложении, я так понимаю, сказуемое одно - ТЯНУТ, а подлежащее "все" повторяется дважды для усиления смысла. В Вашем варианте разрушается целостность сравнительной конструкции, в которой с бурлаками сравниваются люди и кони.